# Clone Wordpress multi-site // staging to production // AWS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, production, multisite, cloning

I apologize in advance if this isn't the best place to ask this...

My company just set up a site on AWS. It's a Wordpress multisite install. We're looking to create a dev/staging version of the site and a live/prod version. The hosts I've used in the past to do this (GoDaddy and WPEngine) have a simple two- or three-step process to move staging to prod, which will clone both the files and database and change the tables necessary for the switch. I wasn't quite sure how to do this in AWS or if it was even doable at all.

... and if cloning is not possible on AWS, what are some recommendations to manage this process?

Our company's account doesn't allow us to put in tech support tickets on AWS, so I was hoping StackOverflow was the next best thing for getting help. :)

Comment: Which AWS services are you using to host the site? EC2, Elastic Beanstalk, Lightsail?

Comment: I don't think there's an out of the box solution for this. Don't confuse "a simple two- or three-step process" you mention (which is just a CD pipeline _within_ a single provider) with what you are after (which is to switch to AWS from another). A very short Google search brought [this](https://www.clickittech.com/aws/wpengine-migration-to-aws/) up which is a lengthy and somewhat complex process but i doubt there's a simpler way...

Comment: @bwest - I'm asking one of our other devs (the account manager) what they used, and I'll get back to you.

Comment: @marekful - I think you may have misunderstood the question. We've already set things up on AWS with this multisite. We're just trying to set up a dev/prod environment on AWS. I'll edit the question so no one else gets confused.

Comment: Right, sorry. In that case. AWS has its own own tools such as CodePipeline and CodeDeploy but 3rd party solutions can be used, too.

Comment: I haven't checked it in detail, but have you looked at a plugin solution? [This one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-staging/) seems to create a subdirectory for the staging site and handles the staging URL stuff itself. I've not tried it, but maybe worth looking into?

Comment: @bwest we're using EC2.

Comment: @indextwo I saw that while researching, and unfortunately, it hasn't been tested on migrating multi-sites. I think the whole multi-site setup kinda throws a wrench in some of our options.

Comment: @BrittanyLayneRapheal Yeah, unfortunately that's often the way with multisite. I've always built workarounds precisely for that reason - MU can turn out to be a sledgehammer used to drive home a drawing pin ¯\_(ツ)_/¯